# FlowPlayer on Android Emulator not visible

Tags: android, android-emulator, flowplayer

So I've made HTML that works fine on my laptop browser that streams audio and tried making a WebView to view the FlowPlayer. I've enabled JavaScript, turned set the plugin state to on and installed the Flash Player .apk on the emulator. For some reason I can't view the audio player on the webview. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Try using an actual device. Often times apps don't work well on an emulator, but work great on a device.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to one.